# Screen Shot to NSImageView

Tags: objective-c, macos

im working on an application for OS X. Right now how I do it is i take a screen shot then use an NSOpenPanel to choose the screen shot. My question is: Is there any way I could click on a button, then it starts the screen shot grabber (when you press Command + Shift + 4) then after I drag and release it would put it into an NSImageView.

Comment: Please don't include "So if anyone has any ideas, please let me know!, Thank you so much!, ~ Will", etc. in your question. It is useless noise.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. I wont do it in the future

Answer (score 0):

See this article on [CocoaDev](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/ScreenShotCode). It looks similar to what you are trying to accomplish.  There are a lot of code examples that should be helpful.